# call a function from other/Program python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, call, func

`First program: first.py

```
list=["ab","cd","ef"]
for i in list:
    with open("input.txt", "w") as input_file:
        print(" {}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

Expected Output:

```
ab
cd
ef
```

But i got Output:

```
ef
```

Second Program: second.py

```
input_file = open('input.txt','r')     

for line in input_file:
    if "ef" in line:
       print(line)
```

Expected Output:

```
ef
```

Got Ouput:

```
ef
```

Now i want to call directly the text file(input.txt) from first.py and use it in second.py ?`How to call a function from other program  python?

Edit: Applied code blocks

Comment: Hi! Please format your code using the editor so it is readable.

Comment: i changed the format

Comment: `list` is a reserved word in python. When you assign a value to it you lose all of that word's functionality. Basically if you tried calling `list(something)` you will get a `TypeError`. DO NOT use keywords or reserved words as variable names!

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the file in a `for` loop, and with the `w` as the mode parameter for the `open` function it makes `open` overwrite the file it opens, which is why you only get the output from the last iteration of the loop.

You should open the file outside the loop instead:

```
with open("input.txt", "w") as input_file:
    for i in list:
        print("{}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

Comment: No comment on the use of `list` as a variable?

Comment: Thanks a lot. one more question how to import that function in second.py and call please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `first.py`, change your code like this.

> `w` mode is for write operation. In each iteration of for loop you are overwriting the last content and writing the new one. So `input.txt` was having `ef` in that (finally).

```
list=["ab","cd","ef"]

for i in list:
    with open("input.txt", "a+") as input_file:
        print("{}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

And now you will get what you expected from this. Now `input.txt` will have the following unlike with your case.

```
ab
cd
ef
```

> **Note:** But if you will will run `first.py` 2nd time, it will continue to add as `a+` creates file if file does not exist otherwise it appends.
>   For better working of this code use **os.path** module's `exists()` function.

And if you want to call the code available in `first.py` then wrap it inside the function. Then import that function in `second.py` and call.

For example

First make sure `first.py` and `second.py` are in the same directory.

> first.py

```
def create_file(file_name):
    list=["ab","cd","ef"]
    for i in list:
        with open(file_name, "a+") as input_file:
            print(" {}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

> second.py

```
from first import create_file

def read_file(file_name):
    # Create file with content
    create_file(file_name)

    # Now read file content
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r')     
    for line in input_file:
        if "ef" in line:
           print(line)

read_file('input.txt')
```

> Open terminal, navigate to this directory, run `python second.py`.

[https://www.learnpython.org/en/Module...](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages) | [https://www.digitalocean.com...](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3) | [https://www.programiz.com/pytho...](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/modules) would be the helpers for you if you want to read and try **how to create module/package** in Python.

> **Update**: The above has a problem as you have mentioned in comment, in each each run, it will append the content. Let's fix it with a little change to `first.py` as follows.

```
import os

def create_file(file_name):
    l = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]

    if os.path.exists(file_name): # If file `input.txt` exists (for this example)
        os.remove(file_name)      # Delete the file

    for i in l:
        with open(file_name, "a+") as input_file:
            print(" {}".format(i), file = input_file)
```

That is it (update in comment if you are stuck).

Comment: Thanks a lot. one more question how to call that input.txt file for second.py program  directly instead of calling like this -->  input_file = open('input.txt','r')

Comment: how to import that function in second.py and call please give me a solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and I am sorry for answering your query late.

Comment: thanks a lot. when i run the code for first time i got the correct output but when i run again it print the answer twice then again i run the code it print thrice ..i dont know why pls suggest me

Comment: Okay got it. You mean in each run, you want only the same o/p. Do one thing, Just check if file exists or not. If it exists, delete it and recreate it. So in one run, only the contents of the list will be written to the file. In 2nd session, program will detect the existence and delete it. Again it will create  the same as before. Just check I have updated my answer. I have kept my old too so that you could understand the difference properly.

Comment: You are welcome `@pythoncoder` and if you are a fan of file handling looking to access file system in an object oriented (OO) way then you can check my article on LinkedIn (with basic screenshots) or can read the documentation of my GitHub repo at [https://github.com/hygull/try-pathlib](https://github.com/hygull/try-pathlib).

Comment: Repeatedly opening the file in the output loop is very inefficient. Better to open it once, and *then* loop. Then you can open it in `'w'` mode, too.

Comment: I have one doubt ...in second.py file i cannot able to read the length of the input file. Currently i m using for line in range(len(input_file)) but i m getting error

Comment: If you want to get the length of input file use `len(input_file.read())`. If you get any issues, write back, I will update my answer then (later).

Comment: And if you are looking for counting lines then the best approach would be `len(input_file.readlines())`.